# Is it good practice to use with along (with db as db) sqlalchemy

Tags: jwt

Is it good practice to use with along (with db as db) sqlalchemy
or is it better to use Fastapi Depends

I implement authorization through jwt fastapi but with real db not fake as it was in the documentation.  How to do it best

Answer (score 1):

according to FastAPI documentation:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

use Depends

Comment: no, I kind of made a script to create a superuser like in Django, and to access the db session I use the operator (with as)